# data frame columns formating

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have multiple data sets which is concatenated in one master file using code below.

```
all_data = pd.DataFrame()
dfs = (pd.read_excel(f, index_col=0, skiprows=8, skipfooter=1, usecols=[0,1])
           for f in filenames)
all_data = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1)
```

The data looks in "each file" looks  like these:(attached)
ID VALUE

Concatenated master file now has like this:

```
ID value  value value value value value value value
```

However, we would like to rename the each value in master  file to have the  file name such as :

Basically replacing the default col in data frame(value) to file names as individual col instead.
Please guide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change column names by simply setting the `df.columns` attribute to some other list. In this case, it looks like your list would be `['ID',file1,file2,...]`

Since those filenames are included in the path in your `filenames` list, we can pull out just the filename and make a new list with those.

```py
columns = list()
for path in filenames: #loop through your filenames list
    file = path.split('\\')[-1] #this splits the path by the '\' character, and returns the last element, so the filename. You need the double-slash since the slash is the escape character from the string, or whatever they call it.
    file = file[:-4] # the file has the .xls on the end. this removes the last 4 characters
    columns.append(file)
all_data.columns = columns #all_data is our dataframe, and all_data.columns is the attribute of the dataframe that contains the column names. Changing this object to our columns list that we made will change the column names in the dataframe.
```

Comment: Thank you Scot. Can you please help rearrange the code. I am new to python and learning peices by peices. I really do not know whcih sequence do I have to run this query .all_data = pd.DataFrame()
dfs = (pd.read_excel(f,index_col =0,skiprows=8,skipfooter=1,usecols=[0,1]) for f in filenames)
all_data = pd.concat(dfs,axis =1)
columns = filenames
columns.insert(0,'ID')
all_data.columns = columns

Comment: all_data = pd.DataFrame()
dfs = (pd.read_excel(f,index_col =0,skiprows=8,skipfooter=1,usecols=[0,1]) for f in filenames)
all_data = pd.concat(dfs,axis =1)
columns = filenames
columns.insert(0,'ID')
all_data.columns = columns

Comment: @SweetyVaidya, it is hard to read the code in the comments since we don't get proper linebreaks in comments (not your fault). You should be able to put my three lines at the end of that first codeblock that you have in your original post. I'll add comments into my original post, in the code-block, to say what each line is doing.

Comment: Hi Scot I received this error Please advise. error: length mismatched: ecpected axis has 2 elements, new values have 3 elements

Comment: columns =filenames.copy()  columns.insert(0,'Employee ID:') all_data.columns = columns

Comment: Get rid of the `columns.insert()` line. As the error says, your new list of columns has too many elements. I'm guessing that the 'ID' from your original is an index instead of an actual column, and so renaming columns shouldn't include it.

Comment: yay....very close. Now the new cols appered as the entire path of the file like w.\my path\pto.01.01.21.xls. I there a way to get rid of path and only file name as the col header . In this case I wnat just pto.01.01.21 .. please

Comment: oh my god Scot. You are extremly talented and helpful. God bless you

Comment: ha, thanks. would you mind marking the answer as correct?

Comment: one final question: When I  ran all_data.columns the result is Index(['PTO.01.01.21.', 'PTO.01.02.21.'], dtype='object') which is perfect. However the first col i.e Employee ID: is not showing up in that statement. I even tired to rename that col as Final_data =all_data.rename(columns = {'Employee ID:': 'ID'},inplace =False) but still my new data frame  Final_data.columns resulting same Index(['PTO.01.01.21.', 'PTO.01.02.21.'], dtype='object')

Comment: The 'index' isn't really a column, it is an index, and so renaming the columns won't rename it. I'm assuming that the 'ID' is stored as an index here. So when you run `df.columns`, you get just the columns, not that index. You can rename the index itself via `df.Index.rename(newname, inplace=True/False)`.  And if you want the 'ID' to be a column and not the index, you can do `df.reset_index(inplace=True)`, and it'll make it a normal column and make a new index incrementing 0:n-1

Comment: Mindblowing guidance Scot. Python has to pay you royalty for  turning  me - "' the SAS programmer" into python. Hats off to you